# load data select2 yii2 when page loading

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii2, jquery-select2

I have wizard form and in step 2 in my form have two select2 Krajee when I click on the first select2 request send to server with Ajax and the second select 2 filled with the data response from server and there isn't any problems, when i going to next step (step 3) and when I want to came back to step 2 I have problem 
, when I came to previous steps I echo the entered value in that field , for this section I echo the selected Id in select 2 but I have problem , my second select 2 depends on first select and when I change first Select 2 the second select is fill , when i came back the first select2 perhaps not changing and the user just want to change second select 2 but in second select2 i Have just the id the user select how can I change my code when page is load or any things the second 2 filled with ajax request in yii2 and select2 or jquery

Comment: salam mohammad.please provice your codes to us

Comment: hi ebrahim i don't think my code help for this section , because  I don't write code for this , and I don't know what to do for this section , i just write code when click on first select2   the second select 2 is filled

Comment: Perhaps you were looking for scenario like update that you get previously selected value in select2 and dependent values in second select2 dropdown. Have a look at [my tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VBm3z3qIbR4&t=274s) seek to last few minutes.